# How do I get all the data in a row of a CSV from defining the text in the first cell of the row?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to do this by using 'Apple' in the iloc but it gave me a traceback. I know that when using iloc, anything in [] has to be an integer so how would I find a cell-like 'Apple'

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('SHARADAR_SF1_aafe962511a67db10c0a72fe536305b0.csv', usecols=['ticker','datekey','assets','eps','pe','price','revenue'])

print(file1.iloc['Apple'])
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/George Adamopoulos/Desktop/All My Files/Neptune Financial Inc/The White Tiger JV/Research/20 Variables Research Code/DataReader.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(file1.iloc['Apple'])
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1767, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2134, in _getitem_axis
    raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

A few lines of the CSV:

```
ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,lastupdated,assets,assetsavg,cashneq,debt,debtc,debtusd,divyield,deposits,eps,epsusd,equity,equityavg,liabilities,netinc,pe,price,revenue
A,ARQ,1999-12-31,2000-03-15,2020-09-01,7107000000,,1368000000,665000000,111000000,665000000,0,0,0.3,0.3,4486000000,,2621000000,131000000,,114.3,2246000000
A,ARQ,2000-03-31,2000-06-12,2020-09-01,7321000000,,978000000,98000000,98000000,98000000,0,0,0.37,0.37,4642000000,,2679000000,166000000,,66,2485000000
A,ARQ,2000-06-30,2000-09-01,2020-09-01,7827000000,,703000000,129000000,129000000,129000000,0,0,0.34,0.34,4902000000,,2925000000,155000000,46.877,61.88,2670000000
A,ARQ,2000-09-30,2001-01-17,2020-09-01,8425000000,,996000000,110000000,110000000,110000000,0,0,0.67,0.67,5265000000,,3160000000,305000000,37.341,61.94,3372000000
A,ARQ,2000-12-31,2001-03-19,2020-09-01,9208000000,,433000000,556000000,556000000,556000000,0,0,0.34,0.34,5541000000,,3667000000,154000000,21.661,36.99,2841000000
```

Comment: Does `print(file1.loc["Apple"])` work? From `help(pd.DataFrame.iloc)` _Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position._

Comment: It doesn't, I get a KeyError: 'A'

Comment: Can you post a several line example of the input csv? I don't think your dataframe rows are indexed yet. You may want to add `index_col="ticker"` so that becomes the row index, but then "Apple" isn't a ticker symbol.

Comment: I just put the sample in the question. I realised that 'Apple' wasn't the right ticker but even when I tried other ones that were right ex: 'A' I still got the same output...

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv` documentation is confusing and behavior in unexpected, IMHO. By default, pandas will infer a header, index and data types from the first few lines of the CSV file. If the header has one fewer cells than the first data line, it will assume that the first column is an index (also referred to as label) for the dataframe.

If the header and first row have the same column count, it will instead generate an integer index starting from 0. That's what happened in your case. Dataframes have two methods, `.loc` to get the rows with a given label (aka, index) and `.iloc` to get the "ith" integer row regardless of index.

If you try `file1.iloc["A"]`, that's the integer index and "A" isn't an integer. If you try `file1.loc["A"]`, the dataframe isn't indexed by ticker so it doesn't work either.

The solution is to name the index when you read the CSV, or `file1 = file1.set_index("ticker")` later.

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
    usecols=['ticker','datekey','assets','eps','pe','price','revenue'],
     index_col="ticker")
print(file1.loc['A'])
```

results in

```
           datekey      assets   eps      pe   price     revenue
ticker                                                          
A       2000-03-15  7107000000  0.30     NaN  114.30  2246000000
A       2000-06-12  7321000000  0.37     NaN   66.00  2485000000
A       2000-09-01  7827000000  0.34  46.877   61.88  2670000000
A       2001-01-17  8425000000  0.67  37.341   61.94  3372000000
A       2001-03-19  9208000000  0.34  21.661   36.99  2841000000
```

This mixing of "index", "label", "loc" and "iloc" could drive a fellow to distraction.

Answer (score 1):

use `loc` instead of `iloc`, because `iloc` works with index values (integers), where as `loc` can work with column names, also make sure you have an index in your DB with the name `Apple`.

Comment: I get this: KeyError: 'A'

Comment: kindly send the output of `file1.index`

Comment: There's no output, it's just blank... not sure what that means

Comment: that means you db doesn't have indices which is quite odd, does `file1.head()` returns anything?

Comment: No again, it's just blank. : Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Make sure that your db is within your working directory